# react-redux get width of component's parent div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is part of the component :

```
import MyComp from '../../lib/MyComp'

const Data = ( { data } ) => (
    <div className="data-box" id="data-box">
        <MyComp data={data} />
    </div>
)
```

How do I get the width of the `data-box` div inside **MyComp** container?

Answer (score 13):

Check this working demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/tgebf8xc/1/):

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div id="parent">Hello Parent<Child></Child></div>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    alert('Parent width: ' + this.refs.child.parentNode.clientWidth);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div ref="child">Hello Child</div>;
  }
});
```

Stating `ref="child"` will make the element accessable by the component itself, through `this.refs.child`. It is the vallina node instance. Using `this.refs.child.parentNode.clientWidth` will return the parent's width. Or, use `this.refs.child.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()`.

Reference: [React refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. JSFiddle link is dead.

Comment: note: this.refs can only be accessed within the componentDidMount / componentDidUpdate lifecycle methods of class-based react components

Answer (score 1):

You need to use react refs.

on your MyComp class:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {

  //All your PropTypes and functions...

  //New function
  newFunction () {
    console.log(this.refs.refName);
    //This will give you the Data component. There you can call methods to calculate width, or whatever you need to do with that component
  }

  //Your render function
  render() {
    return <div ...whatever you have... ref="refName">
  }
}
```

You can check [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Answer (score 0):

what should work is something like this
MyComp could look like this

```
render() {
  return <div ref="node"></div>
}
```

with `this.refs.node` you get the current dom element and with

```
this.res.node.parentNode
```

you should get the parentNode

Comment: Should be this.refs.node.parentNode